# React infinite loop on router route

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm getting an infinite loop whenever the following line of code is being runned

`<Route exact path='/' component={App} />`

i get an infinite loop, i think its because react doesnt know that im referring to the class name `App`, how would i let react know that im referring to the class name ?

the following below works without the `<Route exact path='/' component={App} />`

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import './App.css';
import AddItem from './components/AddItem';
import IndexItem from './components/IndexItem';


class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return(

        <Router>
          <div>
            // <Route exact path='/' component={App} />
            <Route path='/add-item' component={AddItem} />
            <Route path = '/index' component = {IndexItem}/>
          </div>
      </Router>



    )
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: had you tried to wrap the routes using `<Switch>`, instead of div?

Comment: let me try that

Comment: its still in a loop -____-

Comment: Well it's because the `App` component renders itself, so that causes an infinite loop. The component you render for the root path should be its own component e.g. `<Home/>` that you import and render in `App`, like the other routes are.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are rendering `<App />` inside of `<App />`.

Your react app's index.js is rendering the  component. When the App component renders, the "/" route matches and attempts to render the  component again. Thus, infinite loop.

Comment: how would i fix this ?

Comment: There is no need to conditionally render <App /> inside of <App />. In other words, <App /> is already rendering, you don't need to add a specific react-router-dom <Route> render <App />.

Answer (score 0):

My situation was a little different but the accepted answer still led me to the right solution. For me, the infinite rerendering issue was being caused by defining the [Outlet](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/components/outlet) component inside of the component that also used it.

So, I had to change something like this:

```
const Root = () => {
  ...
  const Layout = () => (
    ...
    <Outlet />
    ...
  )

  return (
    <Routes>
      <Route element={<Layout />}>
      ...
  )
}
```

To this instead:

```
const Layout = () => {
  ...
  return (
    ...
    <Outlet />
    ...
  )
}

const Root = () => {
  return (
    <Routes>
      <Route element={<Layout />}>
      ...
  )
}
```